C# HttpClient post request goes behind the servers's response
I ran into the problem of making an post request to a web api using HttpClient of C#. My code is below:
using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://x.x.x.x/");
    var content = new StringContent("*IDN?", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    var response = client.PostAsync("api", content).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var res = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine($"res = {res}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + response.StatusCode);
    }
}

I use Wireshark to capture the packets and the trace looks like:


and I do not get the right response.
While when I use the curl command line
curl -X POST http://x.x.x.x/api -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "*IDN?"

The result is

and I get the right response.

Apparently the order of request and response is reversed. Why? And how to solve this problem?

Try to change this
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var content = new StringContent("*IDN?", Encoding.UTF8);

And use await key word, not use GetAwaiter().GetResult()

@wenming it does not work. "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is the content type of content, not the header.

I didn't get more information, If not working on above, I guest is deadlock problem, check this blog Don't Block on Async Code

I found the way to solve this problem. This page & this page can explain such phenomenon. I am using .net472 and the HttpCliet.Post send two packets, one for header and the other one for the body. But somehow the target machine cannot handle the seperated post packets correctly. When it receives the first packet it responses and will not perform the posted data as expected. I cannot change the .net version so I solved this by platform invoking another dll like wininet.dll.
